# Setting value of element in Typescript object

Tags: typescript

I have defined an object in TS like this:

```
reportObj : {
  'report' : {
    'pk' : '',
    'uploaded' : '',
    'sections' : {
      'section1' : '',
      'section2' : '',
      'section3' : ''
    }
  }
};
```

I want to set the value of section1. How can I do this? I am trying:

```
this.reportObj.report.sections.section1 = data;
```

This fails and I get the error:

> Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'report' of undefined

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do that again without the `this.` prefix.

Comment: reportObj is a class member.

Comment: I defined it inside a function and straight away printed it in the console, but I get undefined. 

I don't think an object is being created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition for the type should be:

```
reportObj: {
  'report': {
    'pk': string,
    'uploaded': string,
    'sections': {
      'section1': string,
      'section2': string,
      'section3': string
    }
  }
};
```

---

#### Edit

Defining the variable/member type doesn't assign a value to it.
This:

```
let reportObj: {
    report: {
        pk: string,
        uploaded: string,
        sections: {
            section1: string,
            section2: string,
            section3: string
        }
    }
};

console.log(reportObj.report);
```

Will fail at runtime because the variable `reportObj` only has a type, but not a value.
To assign a value:

```
type Reporter = {
    report: {
        pk: string,
        uploaded: string,
        sections: {
            section1: string,
            section2: string,
            section3: string
        }
    }
};

let reportObj = {} as Reporter;

console.log(reportObj.report); // undefined
```

But this will still throw a runtime error:

```
console.log(reportObj.report.pk);
```

This will assign the right value:

```
let reportObj = {
    report: {
        sections: {}
    }
} as Reporter;
```

Comment: Check my revised answer

Comment: And after 6 hours of pain, Nitzan to the rescue! Thanks. I only hope the TS docs explained things this way.

Comment: If you use colon after the variable you define the type which is covered in the ts docs. If you use equals after the variable you assign a value which is just like it's done in javascript so the ts docs don't cover it.